# linux samba server with ntfs external

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, ntfs, samba

good day all

Linux Ubuntu 15.04 - gnome
External HDD - 2TB NTFS

**End result**: Stream media from my external hard drive via linux using Samba

**What I have done/tried:**
Followed a tutorial, setting up a samba with appropriate user account,

I tried creating a symobolik link to my external, adding the group "sambashare" which contains smbuser, cybex, root (cybex is my account)

when connecting on android using es file explorer, I am able to see all shares when anonymous, when trying to login with my user credetials, es file explorer reports server not found (ip is unchanged), when connecting with smbuser, I am able to go 1 level in but not browse actual external contents, I do not have the required permissions

I have changed the owner and user, this is fruitless

Any suggestions?

Comment: If all you want is streaming, you should look at using a DLNA server, such as MiniDLNA. I use Ubuntu a lot, but my main media server is a Windows machine, which where my DLNA server resides, so I can't comment on the performance of MiniDLNA or other Ubuntu servers, but I find DLNA generally easy to set up and maintain, and it is supported by most modern media clients (TVs, tablets, sound systems, etc).

Comment: I am an idiot, I think i will delete the question in 10 min, all I needed to do was instead of adding another user account, I just had to add my own accouint since all files are owned by "me", it solved all my problems

Comment: If you use DLNA you don't need Samba in your Android, or any special configuration.